# Laravel Cashier - How to Check if Stripe Payment was Successful

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Cashier in Laravel 5.1 for stripe payment. I want to check how to create a new database entry only when the stripe payment is successful. I am doing something like this:

```
if ($user->subscribed())
{
        $subscribe = $user->subscription()->increment($totalQuantity);
}
else {
        $subscribe = $user->subscription('monthly')->quantity($totalQuantity)->create($postData['token']);
}

if($subscribe) {
   // Insert into Database
}
```

I thought the stripe subscription will return true or false so I can check if the last payment was successful and proceed. But the **`$subscribe`** is empty.

How can I check if the last stripe payment was successful before I proceed with the DB insert queries? I have read the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/billing#checking-subscription-status) and it only mentioned about checking the overall subscription like using

```
`if ($user->subscribed())`
```

but it doesn't mention about how to check if the last stripe subscription charge was successful. How will I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to look at the "handling failed subscriptions" and "handling other webhooks" sections. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/billing#handling-failed-subscriptions

Webhooks are where a 3rd party does a callback to a URL for your application. For example, with stripe someone has just subscribed and made the payment, stripe will then visit a URL of your application with various information about whether that payment was decline, successful, etc. See https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

You can register the route to your application in your stripe dashboard under Your Account > Account Settings > Webhooks > Add New Endpoint

Comment: Thank you @Wader I read through the links you had given. It appears then that I will not be able to check the status from the same php script instantly before proceeding with the next line of scripts like in my OP code sample, isint it? If I had to set-up a separate route to handle failed subscription callbacks, then my understanding is the php script that creates a db entry on succesful payment cant be done instantaneously after the `$user->subscription()` method.

Comment: My scenario is that when the user pays, db tables are created and user is given access to it. If I have to setup a separate route to handle callbacks, I think there could be a brief time the user will have this access until the webhook picks up on failed transaction and changes the settings.

Comment: Just wondering, what will happen  if `$user->subscription()->increment($totalQuantity);` fails for some reason, say stripe website was down or it couldnt add the increment to the subscription for some reason. Will the remaining script that follows the above line stop too or does the remaining script continue to execute to create the table and I will manually need to check the webhook route callback?.Sorry, just trying to get my head around it.

Comment: Thats correct. I'd expect, everything being well with the transaction that it should be a relatively short period between the user handing over card details and the webhook coming through, possibly a matter of minutes. Previously when doing this on services I've worked on the user is given access, be that on a trial or not. If the payment is declined then revoke access to the application.

Comment: At the point details are handed over stripe does check the card is actually real and valid, when you receive a failed payment its because funds have been refused, not that the user has entered dud details, so theres a good chance the payment will come through. If the API call fails for whatever reason, I'd expect an exception to be thrown from guzzle.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you so much @Wader. I should be able to take it from here. Much obliged for your help when I needed it. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the Stripe Charge object's return values. If paid = "true" then the charge is successful.

See this link: https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object